# Invalid JSON Response

Tags: surveymonkey

(As a preface, SurveyMonkey requests that questions to their developers be posted to SO with the tag 'surveymonkey')

We've been calling the SurveyMonkey API without problem until yesterday.  As of yesterday, the response we're getting back seems to contain an invalid JSON string.  The problem seems to lie in the response object containing several unescaped double-quote characters.  Below is an example of the response we're getting when calling **get_survey_details**:

```
"heading": "Please click "Next" below to proceed.\r\n"
```

As you can see, there are two unescaped double-quotes ("Next"), which is resulting in an invalid JSON object error.

To verify that it isn't a problem with our code, I made the same API call via terminal (curl), and got the same response.

Reproducing the issue is as easy as creating a survey with double-quotes in a heading, question text, or answer text, and then calling get_survey_details.

Seeing as this has been working fine up until yesterday, I'm wondering if something has recently changed on the SurveyMonkey end of things?  We're dead in the water until this gets resolved.

Thanks!

Comment: I also started having an issue yesterday with the API, after my code being quite stable. I expect it is something on Survey Monkey's end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the developers, this was an issue on their end.  As of yesterday, they had pushed a fix which resolves this issue.